# How realistic was the sword fight in Rob Roy?

Tags: realism, rob-roy

[One previous question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2811/is-the-sword-fighting-historically-accurate) asked about the authenticity of sword fights in Game of Thrones compared to actual "medieval" sword fighting--a rather vague standard. Naturally, such choreography is made for the screen and pales to movies like the epic duels in *Scaramouche* (1952) which were based on real fencing moves. Of course, while realistic, to what extent this Olympic-style fencing represented the state of the art in 18th century France is debatable.

My question concerns not Scaramouche, but the movie *Rob Roy* (1995). I wonder what modern saber experts think of the final duel in that movie and how real to life it was?

Comment: The question requires "modern saber experts" to know the authentic fighting style of circa 1713 Scottish swordsmanship.  Was the question intended to ask how authentic the movie depicts modern saber fighting style regardless of whether or not such style would be used in 1713?

Comment: @JamesOlson Right, I am expecting there are modern saber experts who have knowledge of 18th century swordsmanship. As an expert chess player, I know exactly the skill and practices of 18th century chess players, and I assume there are saber experts who have the same kind of knowledge in their own field. For example, if an 18th-century chess game was depicted on screen, I could tell you how realistic or unrealistic it was because I know the openings, tactics and style of play used back in those days by Philidor, Labordonnais, and other masters of those times.

Comment: `I wonder what modern saber experts think of the final duel` You do realise that neither party uses a saber.

Comment: @Grimm The duel shown is what today would be analogous to a saber duel. The difference between saber and foil (or rapier) is that a saber is an edged weapon so the fighter can win by either slashing or stabbing. Rapiers (today would be foil or epee) are only effective as stabbing weapons.

Comment: @TylerDurden It would be analogous to a broadsword/backsword vs smallsword/spadroon duel, which is what the weapons are most like. A good discussion of the duel is here: https://youtu.be/KlsT9VZyehE If you want to see clips of people studying treatises of similar weapons go to your favourite video sharing site and look for "George Silver Backsword" "English martial arts backsword" and "AHF smallsword". Sit back and geek out. :-)